# Error when archiving iOS application swift

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, app-store

I am trying to upload my app to the app store, but when I archive the app, I get an error saying, "No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue". It gives me an option to fix the issue, and when I press it, I get another error saying, "Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer." And an error saying, "codeSign Error: code signing is required for product type "Application in SDK "iOS 8.4". What is causing this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this

> codeSign Error: code signing is required for product type "Application in SDK "iOS 8.4

open Build Settings of your target => Code Signing

then change "Don't Code Sign" to yours for "Code Signing Identity" row

You either could generate a provision profile by yourself in your developer account on developer.apple.com. After you need to download it and say to the xcode to use it (Build Settings => Code Signing => Provision Profile, if the xcode doesn't see the downloaded provision have to add it to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ folder). After all try to  restart the xcode, clean up the last build and build all over again.